# How can you match a field in Thinky ORM?

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb, thinky

I am trying check if one field from a table does exists (Case In-sensitive) using **Thinky ORM**. Without **Thinky**, I can **match** a field just using RethinkDB simple **filter-match** operations:

```
//  This makes my variable insensitive.
let myFieldInsensitive = '(?i)^' +myFieldSensitive`enter code here`+'$';
//  Filter by matching myFieldInsensistive.
r.table('myTable').filter(r.row('myField').match(myFieldInsensitive))
 .run(myConnection, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result.length); // returns 1 if myFieldInsesitive was found
})
```

This code will check if the **mySpecificField** does exists yet in **myTable** (Case In-sensitive).

Now, I am trying to do the same **match** using **Thinky**, but this **ORM** does not support this syntax:

```
let myFieldInsensitive = '(?i)^' +myFieldSensitive+'$';
myModel.filter(('myField').match(myFieldInsensitive)})
  .run().then((result) => {
    console.log(result.length); // should return 1 if myFieldInsesitive was found, but this returns always empty array
})
```

Does anybody has idea about how can you **match** data in a table using **Thinky**?

Comment: Nice that you got it to work. :) Consider adding it as an answer below instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally did it! I have included **thinky.r**:

`let r = thinky.r;`

Instead of writing

`myModel.filter(('myField').match(myFieldInsensitive))`

I wrote

`myModel.filter(r.row('myField').match(myFieldInsensitive))`

**VOILA**!